# Node Express chaining functions returns UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm breaking up a Node Endpoint so that 2 things happen

1. Checks if User Exists
2. Adds user to the database

**controller.js**

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  methods.checkUser('email', req.body.email)
    .then(methods.addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password))
    .then(() => {
      res.send('added');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(403).send(err);
    });
};
```

**methods.js**

```
exports.checkUser = (key, val) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?', ['users', key, val], (err, result) => {
      if (result) {
        resolve(result);
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }

    });
  });
};

exports.addUser = (email, password) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (email === 'test@domain.com') {
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      console.log('rejecting');
      reject(email);
    }
  });
};
```

`addUser()` currently just checks if the email `===` `test@domain.com` to test out the Promise chain.

So the endpoint returns `added` in Postman

But Terminal shows the following

```
rejecting
(node:71904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): bot@domain.com
(node:71904) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Typically I would have wrote it like this.

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  methods.checkUser('email', req.body.email)
    .then(() => {
      methods.addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        .then(() => {
          res.send('added');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(403).send(err);
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(403).send(err);
    });
};
```

I want to take a cleaner approach but need help

Comment: You need to pass functions to `.then()`, not promises.  So, for example: `.then(methods.addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password))` needs to be `.then(() -> methods.addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password))` or `.then(methods.addUser.bind(methods, req.body.email, req.body.password))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct way to write the Promise chain:

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    methods.checkUser('email', req.body.email)
      .then(() => methods.addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password) )
      .then(() => res.send('added') )
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(403).send(err);
      });
  };
```

so in case of a `reject` in the chain, like in the case of the `email=bot@domain.com` input in the example, the rejection will be handled by the last `catch`.